# QDialog with floating toolbar

Tags: qt, toolbar, qdialog

How can I create a `QDialog` with floating toolbar in Qt?

Attachment of the `QMainWindow` with toolbar as widget in the `QDialog` is not suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Why not suitable? following code works like charms.

```
#include <QtGui>

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDialog(QWidget* parent=0)
    {
        QMainWindow* child = new QMainWindow;
        QLabel* label = new QLabel(tr("QMainWindow with toolbar!"));
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        child->setCentralWidget(label);

        QToolBar* toolbar = child->addToolBar(tr("Tool"));
        toolbar->addAction(tr("Test"), this, SLOT(doTest()));

        QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
        layout->addWidget(child);
    }
private slots:
    void doTest()
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Test"), tr("ToolBar is Working!"));
    }
};
```

Comment: QMainWindow is too heavy. May be I'm not precisely formulated question. It is more correct : how can I create a Qwidget with floating toolbar in qt? if I want to create more than one toolbar for different widgets in one Dialog?

Comment: Just floating only toolbar could be easily done because it is QWidget-derived and you can make QWidget as popup window any time I believe. But if you want make it docking/floating switchable, it seems there is no other choice except using QMainWindow.  And one more thing. what do you mean by "QMainWindow is heavy?". Does QMainWindow works slow?

Answer (score 0):

look at
[Can you add a toolbar to QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435801/can-you-add-a-toolbar-to-qdialog/18436011#18436011)
and try to write smth like that

```
myDialog->layout()->setMenuBar(myToolBar);
```