# Can you add a toolbar to QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, qmainwindow, qdialog

I'm working on a project that needs to call a modal window with a toolbar to do some work on some data before it's loaded. The reason I need the toolbar is the user has a few different possible options that can be combined.

The obvious choice here is a Modal dialog (which I have working right now). The issue is I want a toolbar. This is a two part question:

1. Is it possible to add a toolbar to a `QDialog`? (also is it possible to do this in Qt Designer?)
2. If 1. is not possible, how can I make a `QMainWindow` modal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the built-in drag and drop feature of QMainWindow's toolbars, you can simply add a QToolBar to any layout, including QDialog's layout(). See the [DigviJay Patil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28343489/1951907) below for details, which is definitely cleaner conceptually.

Otherwise, please read on.

---

1. It is not *directly* possible to add a `QToolBar` to a `QDialog` in the QMainWindow::addToolBar() sense, because `QDialog` inherits only `QWidget` and not `QMainWindow`, as you noted (hence do not have the method `addToolBar()`)
2. You can't make a `QMainWindow` modal, but you can insert a `QMainWindow` in a `QDialog` this way:

Code:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog() :
    QDialog()
{
    QMainWindow * mainWindow = new QMainWindow(); // or your own class
                                                  // inheriting QMainWindow

    QToolBar * myToolBar = new QToolBar();
    mainWindow->addToolBar(myToolBar);

    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(mainWindow);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Indeed, a `QMainWindow` doesn't necessarily have to be a top-level widget, and you can even insert several `QMainWindow`s as children of a single widget (may not be the wisest choice though, as the user would probably be confused with the separate sets of menu bars, toolbars, dock widgets, etc.).

Comment: The next question would have to be: is this best practice in my situation? I assume I'm going to have to hand-build the Qmainwindow without the convenience of Qt designer right?

Comment: I've never used Qt Designer: isn't it possible to graphically insert a QMainWindow inside another widget? Anyway, another option is to use a vertical layout with two widgets: on top your QToolBar, and on bottom whatever you wanted as a "central widget". Again, This is doable for sure manually, but maybe Qt Designer prevents the possibility to use a QToolBar outside a QMainWindow. But be careful, from the documentation: `When a QToolBar is not a child of a QMainWindow, it loses the ability to populate the extension pop up with widgets added to the toolbar using addWidget().`

Comment: This worked, had to remove and stuff to get it to look right but that seems to be quick. Thanks.

Comment: I implemented the solution and it works, but now user can move the toolbar from top to left, right or bottom of the dialog window. Is there a way to fix the position of toolbar in this example?

Edit: Solution to above question is: myToolBar->setMovable(false);

Yet i have another question: if we use toolbar in main window, it clings to the top and seems well. But in this solution, I could not find a way to cling the toolbar/layout to the window. Is there a way?

Comment: BE CAREFUL! Your mainWindow has not any parent. You will have memory leak when the dialog is deleted. The instruction layout->addWidget(mainWindow) does NOT set ownership.  You should do a mainWindow.setParent(this)

Comment: @pablo_worker I think you are incorrect. `layout->addWidget()` does not set ownership right away, but `setLayout` should. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html. `The layout will automatically reparent the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of the widget on which the layout is installed`

Comment: I looked at Qt 4.8 source code, [setLayout()](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/4.8/src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L9809) does indeed the job of parenting. The relevant call is `l->d_func()->reparentChildWidgets(this);`, where the function reparentChildWidgets is defined [here](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/gui/kernel/qlayout.cpp#L957).

Comment: **This is demonstrably awful.** While `QMainWindow` *does* subclass `QWidget` and is thus generically reusable as a standard widget, doing so is extreme overkill in all possible use cases (including this one), is aesthetically unappealing without significant manual intervention, *and* invites subtle issues relating to the fact that a `QMainWindow` embedded within another `QWidget` is no longer a main window at all. Instead, see *any* of the other answers below – all of which are blatantly superior. This should *not* be the accepted answer.

Comment: @CecilCurry Thanks for your comment :) I do agree with oversight (this answer of mine is 5 years old now) that the solution I proposed here is overkill in many situations, and that I'd use DigviJay Patil's solution myself in some situations. I edited my answer to reflect this. However, I'd still not qualify my answer as "demonstrably awful". It works perfectly fine, and there are only two other answers: one is irrelevant (menubars instead of toolbars), and the other does not provide as much functionality. Therefore, it is not blatantly superior IMHO; it just has different pros and cons.

Answer (score 27):

You can simply use the setMenuBar function of the layout manager that is installed on your QDialog:

```
myDialog->layout()->setMenuBar(myMenuBar);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add QToolBar in QDialog. But as a QWidget. Please have a look

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
   QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

   QToolBar *toolBar = new QToolBar();
   mainLayout->addWidget(toolBar);

   QAction *action1 = new QAction("Add", toolBar);
   QAction *action1 = new QAction("Del", toolBar);

  //Add What you want
}
```

As QToolBar is child of QWidget we can add it as Widget. Using Layout you can adjust its position. Please check this link   http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_QToolBar_and_QToolButton_in_Qt

Comment: This is the correct approach imo, instead of using a whole `QMainWindow` solely for this purpose