# Change content of a menu bar in different stack widget page in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Forgive me if this question is silly but I want to know

> if there is a way to change the content of a menu bar in different
>   page on a stacked widget directly in qt designer.

For example I want the menu of the menu bar for page 1 of the stacked widget to be menu, inbox, multimedia, exit. For the second page I want the menu bar to contain the following menu; Text, outbox, contact, back. The reason is because

> I want different menu controls for different pages of the
>   QstackeWidget. Is this possible from the qt designer ui or I'll have
>   to ultimately do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (which is QtCreator 3.3.0) the Creator only supports graphically inserting and editing a menu bar in QMainWindow. So for the first part of your question: Yes, you probably have to create the menus programmatically.

For the second part, it is possible to insert a menu bar in any given layout using `QLayout::setMenuBar`. This also includes the layout *inside* your stacked widget.

See also: [Can you add a toolbar to QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435801/can-you-add-a-toolbar-to-qdialog)